# Volume control on asus zenbook 3

Tags: sound, hardware

Using Ubuntu 16 LTS

I installed ubuntu on my new asus zenbook3 ux390. Nearly everything works fine except the volume controls don't work. The volume is either on or off. I can adjust volume in specific apps or websites (like youtube) successfully, but the internal volume control either wants to be muted or at 100%.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using 16.04 or 16.10?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem may be related to Ubuntu not detecting all your speakers correctly. I solved all sound related problems on my Zenbook (UX390UA) by editing:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common
```

and changing this section:

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

Into this:

```
[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore


[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right


[Element LFE]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
```

save (with Ctrl+x) and restart pulse audio:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Source: [Ubuntu 16.10 on Asus Zenbook 3 UX390 - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2340639&p=13581528#post13581528)

PS: This also works on Asus Zenbook 3 UX490 and Asus Zenbook Pro UX550VE

Comment: This also works for updating POP_OS 18.10 on a Dell XPS 13.

Comment: Thanks, this also worked on Fedora. Instead of reboot `pulseaudio -k` also works.

Comment: This also works on openSUSE, both the current version of Tumbleweed and Leap 15. Thank you!

Comment: Also did this on Fedora with an Asus Zenbook UX390U

One addition though is that I had to edit the `[Element Master]` section in `analog-output-headphones.conf` from `volume = merge` to `volume = ignore` otherwise my headphones would be stuck on an extremely low volume