# Sound troubles with ASUS ZenBook UX490U

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, asus, volume-control

Well, my problem is that I press the volume control on the keyboard, I see the bar in the screen going down, but it doesn't do anything until it's at 0. So the volume is on 0 or 100%.

I have done many things trying to fix it. Finally, I did something that I read here [How do I change the way Ubuntu adjusts my volume mixer levels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15069/how-do-i-change-the-way-ubuntu-adjusts-my-volume-mixer-levels#new-answer?newreg=bb6bd1648aab4e97a96cb3f7f39e4ffa) , and it works, but not forever. For example, the solution just remains one song in YouTube. After that, again, very loud sound or silence. I go by the terminal to check `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and everything is ok, like I left it before.

I don't know what to do. I'm getting crazy.
Thank you so much for your time!

EDIT: I had Windows 10 before in this PC, but I reformatted to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. The model is an ASUS ZENBOOK UX490U. And finally, typing `lspci -v | grep -i vga` in the terminal, I get this:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620
>   (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Comment: 1) Which version of Ubuntu are you using? 2) Which release number? 3) Was it a new install or an upgrade from a previous version? 4) What's the make and model of your PC? Please get the model number from the sticker on the bottom which also has the serial number; other model numbers on top, front, bezels, lids, or surrounds don't provide the info we need.  5) Please run `lspci -v | grep audio` in a terminal; copy the results, then come back here and click [edit] to provide that info as well as the answers to 1-4.

Comment: Please check this answer if you have ZenBook. https://askubuntu.com/questions/906303/volume-control-on-asus-zenbook-3