# Sound level is 0 or 100, nothing between

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, asus

I have an Asus UX390UA that run Ubuntu 20.04.1.
I have sound problem, when I try to adjust sound level, 0% is working well, but from 1 to 100% sound level is always 100%

I applied this workaround: [Volume control on asus zenbook 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906303/volume-control-on-asus-zenbook-3)
It worked well before but it's not working anymore on my laptop